# Close Form if Field is Blank

Tags: forms, ms-access, if-statement, vba, runtime-error

I have a form that if a field is blank, it tells the user that it can't be blank, and gives the user the option to fill in the blank field (Yes) or close the form (No).  Problem is that when the user picks No (or close the form), it gives me a run-time error 2585.  After researching, I have it checking if the field is blank on the field after using On Got Focus.  (After Update on the field didn't work because there's no update if it's blank.)  Here's my code:

```
If IsNull(Me.txtSSN) Then

  strMsg = "Social Security Number Must Not Be Left Blank!" & vbCrLf
  strMsg = strMsg & "Do you want to add new veteran's record?" & vbCrLf

  If MsgBox(strMsg, vbQuestion + vbYesNo, "Go to Record?") = vbYes Then

    Me.Undo
    Me.Refresh
    Me.txtSSN.SetFocus
    Exit Sub

  Else
    Me.Undo
    Me.Refresh
    Me.txtSSN.SetFocus

    'DoCmd.OpenForm "fmuMainMenu"
    DoCmd.Close acForm, "frmVetNewMainForm"

  End If
```

Else 
'Rest of Code...

Comment: You can either delete the code line `Me.txtSSN.SetFocus` (it doesnt make sense to focus to something when you close the form anyway) or you fill into the field a **NULL** value before closing. Like `Me.txtSSM = Null`. But I am not sure if that is what you are looking for. Its hard to find out what you rly want to do

Comment: I thought the same thing - change txtSSN to NULL because then there's nothing to save.  Tried both and it didn't work.  Keeps giving me the 2585 error.

Comment: Where do you get the error? Did you debug per line with F8 to look where the error appears? Maybe try `Me!txtSSN.SetFocus` instead of `Me.txtSSN.SetFocus`

Comment: Tried ! - no luck.  Getting error on DoCmd.Close line.

Comment: Well if your error is at the `Docmd.Close` line, check if the from **frmVetNewMainForm** is open at the moment when you want to close it or you misspelled the name of the form.

Comment: It's open and it's not misspelled.

Comment: Thats strange. Can you check the error description. Type in the immediate window `?Err.Description` after the error happened. Maybe this helps

Comment: Thanks for your ideas but nothing is working.  3 forums later, I decided to just tell the user SSN must be entered and have it go back to SSN field.  From there, the user can click a Cancel button.  I really appreciate all your ideas!